# By default does the ui widget lightbox resize based on content?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

One of our vendors announced that they were going to increase the size of our videos.  Bigger height and width.  They play the videos using jquery ui widget.  They said that we may need to look at the css (don't ask why they are doing this) and make changes before the roll out.  My impression was that the ui widget lightbox resizes based on content but I wanted to make sure.

If there is any changes that will be made we will have to add our own css using !important tags to overwrite theirs.

Here is an example of the output:

```
<div style="display: block; z-index: 1002; outline: 0px none; position: absolute; height: auto; width: 350px; top: 2212px; left: 773px;" class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-draggable ui-resizable" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ui-dialog-title-video18812"><div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix"><span class="ui-dialog-title" id="ui-dialog-title-video18812">&nbsp;</span><a href="#" class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all" role="button"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick">close</span></a></div><div id="video18812" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" style="width: auto; min-height: 0px; height: 260.833px;">
```

https://d12b9qr7fag7dm.cloudfront.net/cust/364/WINS_NOMURA_720p.mp4&autostart=true">

Close

Comment: It depends on if the content is "preloaded"

Comment: @SpYk3HH  What do you mean by preloaded?  Also it looks like it is sized with our current video size out of the box.

Comment: As in, if the video html is alerady loaded in defore the lightbox is created. I'm not sure exactly which "widget" you're referring to, but I do know UI modal dialog, as most jquery "lightbox" plugins, will attempt to size beased on content of the inner HTML when the dialog is "initialized". However, if its a one set element, and videos/HTML is loaded in and out, then you'll want to do you own size cal, most likly during the "show" event.

Comment: @SpYk3HH it is the ui modal dialog.  The video is called from a link in the db and is loaded 1 video per lightbox by clicking the "download" link.  This vendor is just so backwards it scares me but I can't see any css where they are manipulating the width/height.  I am guess it is just default css padding around the video and it will adjust based on a larger video.

Comment: Perhaps. Altho, if you'd post some code, I could be much more informational. Although, if what your using is [**this**](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal) and it's being filled dynamically, then chances are you will need to size it during the [open](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-open) event. This is not hard to do, but again, some code would really help me to help you.

Comment: @SpYk3HH - added example of the output.